# How to cut a mesh at the edge?

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-view, edges, knife-tool

Is there a way I can cut by continuing an edge?
[image: Just like this, the red line is where I want the cut]

So I want a cut at the red line, possibility using the knife tool, but I can't use the angle snap, since its not on any particular angle, so is there a way to rotate the camera so its on the same angle as that edge?

Clarification: Where the red line is, it's just grey space. I want an edge there

Comment: Do you prefer a solution with the knife tool, or is any solution that cuts the edge OK?

Comment: I really don't mind how its done, results is what matters right? :D Though... it would be nice to have a function that can rotate camera to the same angle as an edge.

Comment: What do you mean with "same angle as an edge"? =)

Comment: Since the knife tool's angle snap is relative to the viewport, if the viewport angle is rotated so that the diagonal line is horizontal, then the knife tool's angle snap will work the way I want it to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have a face on the edge perpendicular to the front face, then you can select the face and move the view with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>NumPad 1</kbd>. That will rotate the view so that the edge is alined, then the angle constraint in the knife tool will work.
[image: animated gif]